# My event listener won't trigger when I've submitted a form

Tags: jquery, html

I'm just trying to get test printed to console log when the submit button is pressed on the form. Where am I going wrong?

```
<script>
      $('form').submit(function (e) {
      console.log("test")
    })
<script>  

<form  onsubmit="">
        <input name="name" pattern="^[a-zA-Z\d-]+" type="text">
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You have to **preventDefault** the event `submit` (`e.preventDefault` inside the `submit(function())` because when you press the `add` button, this make the form submitted (and refreshing the page) and clearing the console (you can `preserve Log` in console too, if you don't want to **preventDefault**, to see what's consoling in each refresh).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prevent your form's default action using `preventDefault()` like this.

```js
$('form').submit(function(e) {       
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Submitted!!!")
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form  onsubmit="">
        <input name="name" pattern="^[a-zA-Z\d-]+" type="text">
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```